# how to run a nodejs file on azure function using a cron job?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a nodejs file indexjs. How do I run it using azure functions. I mean I see this auto generated file I got from time tiggers but how do I directed to run the file.

like `node index.js`

This is the file I have

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "name": "myTimer",
            "type": "timerTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to follow the documentation to create an Azure function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-node?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbrowser) for CLI or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node) for vs code. Once you create a function within your function app it will automatically create an index.js file that you can edit the code in. Replace what's in the index.js with the code you already have and you should be good to go.